Do control flow in quantum computing works on sequential in run time?
In classical computing, we have notion of compile time and run time?
How about quantum computing? For example from qiskit docs about WhileLoopOp, it accepts body and condition. It seems that we have new notion of transpile time?
I mean, when is the condition evaluated? Because I thought once the abstract circuit transpiled, we can not change the circuit during run time, isn't it?
For example, if a qubit is True then execute body A else body B, but in run time the qubit always True. Does that means the transpiled circuit contains two circuits? Or, just body A (circuit A)?

